# Ways to view events of a loop

Tags: php

Is there a way to view events in a loop? For example I have a code like this:

```
foreach($users as $the_user){

    $user_id = $the_user['user_id'];

    if($the_user['points_request'] == 0){
        $sql = "UPDATE user SET points_request = '20' WHERE user_id = '{$user_id}' ";
        db::query($sql);
        echo "Newly added: ".$the_user['user_fullname'].'</br>';

    }else{
        echo "Already added: ".$the_user['user_fullname'].'</br>';
    }
}
```

So when I run this code it will display the events per line in a `textbox` or in a `div` wrapper. Or maybe show as an alert or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show each line at a time (all the way to the browser):

```
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

foreach($users as $the_user){

    $user_id = $the_user['user_id'];

    if($the_user['points_request'] == 0){
        $sql = "UPDATE user SET points_request = '20' WHERE user_id = '{$user_id}' ";
        db::query($sql);
        echo "Newly added: ".$the_user['user_fullname'].'</br>';

    }else{
        echo "Already added: ".$the_user['user_fullname'].'</br>';
    }
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Just displaying all the outputs at once. Is it possible to display the line(output) at once? When executed ->hide, when executing ->show.

Comment: To see the difference add `sleep(2);` after `flush();`

Comment: Wow!, I didn't know that function. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Last question, How can I add `done` message when the execution finished?

Comment: Add `echo "Done.";` before `ob_end_flush();`. You'are welcome.